# Search algorithm when target is unknown

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, search, graph, artificial-intelligence

Am creating an underwater submarine that has to search a pool for targets that are in unknown locations.  Is there any algorithm that could be used in this case specifically.  I read a bout A* but that seems to only be useful in identifying shortest path when the starting location and target location are known.  A DFS also seems to apply for the same scenario.

Is there any way to do this without traversing the entire pool?

Comment: You are going to need to edit the question to specify the problem much more clearly, if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Idk how much clearer I can be, are there any algorithms that can used to find targets when their location is unknown.  Because I think you would still have to traverse the entire area to find them

Comment: Well, for a start, you could be clear about what inputs and outputs your algorithm should have, and how they are represented as data. Are the submarines integers, strings, objects? Is the pool a list, a 2D grid, a dictionary, a tree? How about including some example data with expected outputs?

Comment: Its actually a real submarine and a real pool.  I think the pool is going to be represented as a tree with nodes once the submarine starts traversing it.  But was looking at the problem from a higher level.

Comment: A *real submarine* and a *real pool*? This isn't much of an algorithm question, then - use sonar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar

Comment: Say we have a 2d robot in a coordinate plane.  And it is looking for an object but does not know where the object is.  Will it have to traverse the entire coordinate plane to find it or are there any algorithms that can be used to prevent searching the entire area.

Comment: Does the submarine occupy just one cell of the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the body of water your submarine traverses to be a graph with cells in it.

Do you have any heuristics for your search algorithm (an approximate measure of how close you are to the target)?

For example, the target could be more likely to be in deeper waters or you might see the target on a camera.

If you have some heuristic, you could do a Dijkstra's algorithm, which is like Breadth-First Search (BFS) for weighted graphs. Then, you explore nodes in increasing order of cost from the starting point. Your priority would be cost from source, if you haven't explored it yet, and approximate cost to explore.

Other than that, I don't really (with the little information given) see a way to do it other than a BFS, DFS, as in exploring every single cell in some order until you find the target.

Of course, all of this changes depending on the inputs you have from your submarine. Maybe your submarine can see or sense (temperature change, sound, radio signal, who knows, etc.) the target!

Answer (score 1):

I answering under assumption that you are talking about a real submarine.

As you seem to not have any information about the locations the only thing you can do is to exhaustively search the pool. The tricky part is, however, how to exhaustively search.

The problem is that you need to have a map of the pool and localize your submarine.
Even with the best sensors perfect localisation is most likely not possible. The algorithm you need is SLAM (simultaneous localisation and mapping).